# WPF toggle visibility between 6 stack panels and hide all others when one is opened

Tags: wpf, xaml, toggle, visibility

I have six stack panel elements that are toggled all by a seperate toggle button which is what I need. However, when the user opens up one of the stack panels I would like to close all of the other ones and just show the one they have clicked on.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="504" Margin="-1,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="760">

    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Background="#FF45B8F9" Margin="1,-1,0,0"/>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Background="#FFF95545" Margin="636,0,0,-1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"/>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Background="#FFF9F945" Margin="507,-1,0,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=button_Copy, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"/>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Background="#FF76F945" Margin="378,-1,0,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"/>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="button" Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Click="button_Click"/>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Click="button_Click"/>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="button1" Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You should really use RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions for a Grid. You said you have 6 stackpanels but I just see 4. Also the number of togglebuttons is not equal to the number of stackpanels (while I thought there should be each togglebutton for each stackpanel).

Comment: I kept it condensed I figured a solution applied to 3 could be applied to 3 more panels. One of the panels is the main control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a RadioButton custom template to display like an Expander:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="GroupName" Value="MyToggleButtonGroupName"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<RadioButton>
    <StackPanel>...</StackPanel>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton>
    <StackPanel>...</StackPanel>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton>
    <StackPanel>...</StackPanel>
</RadioButton>
```